# How to integrate $I(k)=\frac{2\pi}{i k^2}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-ir }-e^{ir }\right)dr$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, distribution-theory

I heard that you can integrate

$$\begin{align}I(k)=\frac{2\pi}{i k^2}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-ir }-e^{ir }\right)dr
\end{align}$$ in the sense of tempered distribution. Unfortunately, I am only familiar with "standard integration", but I need this integral for a physics exercise which is why I wanted to ask here if anybody could show me, how such an integral is calculated?

Comment: This is (up to an unrelated factor) the [Fourier transform of unity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632095/fourier-transform-of-a-unity-function-and-of-unit-step-function). See too [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Fourier_transform).

Comment: $e^{-ir}-e^{ir}=-2i \sin(r)$. The integral of $\sin(r)dr$ is not convergent for $r$ tending to infinity.

Comment: @JJacquelin Sure, but this integral may still exist in the sense of distribution. As Raymond mentioned, $f(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i x \xi}$ is the Fourier transform of the constant function $1$. It is also known as the Dirac delta.

Comment: Of course, it can be understood as the Dirac delta if the limits of the integral are $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. But the raised by Tobias Hurth is different : the limits are $0$ to $+\infty$. This is more problematical than the Fourier transform of the constant function $1$.

Comment: @JJacquelin Why can't we use Fresnell integral here?

Comment: The Fresnel integrales are involved in cases of integration of $\sin(x^2)$ or of $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)}$, not in case of $\sin(x)$. This is very different car the integrals are convergent for $x$ tending to infinity, while they are not convergent in case of $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have finished my answer on your original question even though there was an accepted answer, sorry for that. Seeing that things are not yet clear for you, I chose to post it here instead.

The Fourier transformation $\mathcal{F}$ of a tempered distribution $u \in \mathcal{S}'$ is defined as the "adjoint" of the Fourier transformation on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$, that is $\mathcal{F}u:=u \circ \mathcal{F}$ (or $\forall \phi \in \mathcal{S}: (\mathcal{F}u)(\phi)=u(\mathcal{F}(\phi))$ if you wish). You are given the tempered distribution $u_{\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}} \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ defined through $u_{\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}}(\phi):=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{1}{\vert x \vert} \phi(x) \, \text{d}x$. By dominated convergence, $(\mathcal{F}u_{\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}})(\phi)=\lim\limits_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R^{3}}}\frac{1}{\vert x \vert} e^{-\epsilon \vert x \vert} (\mathcal{F}\phi)(x) \, \text{d}x$. But for $\epsilon > 0$, the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\vert x \vert} e^{-\epsilon \vert x \vert}$ lies in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3}) \cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$, so we may use the direct consequence of Fubini's theorem that $\int f (\mathcal{F}\phi) = \int (\mathcal{F}f) \phi$ for certain functions and compute the Fourier transformation of $\frac{1}{\vert x \vert} e^{-\epsilon \vert x \vert}$ in the usual sense.

For $k \neq 0$ ($k=0$ is easily done), pick $R \in \text{O}(3)$ with $Rk=\vert k \vert e_{3}$. Substituting $x=R^{t}y$ and then changing to polar coordinates gives us for the Fourier transformation
$$\begin{aligned}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R^{3}}}\frac{1}{\vert x \vert} e^{-\epsilon \vert x \vert+i \langle k, x \rangle } \, \text{d}x &= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R^{3}}}\frac{1}{\vert y \vert} e^{-\epsilon \vert y \vert+i \vert k \vert y_{3} } \, \text{d}y = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} e^{-\epsilon r+i \vert k \vert r \cos(\theta) }  r \sin(\theta)\, \text{d}\theta \, \text{d}\phi \, \text{d}r \\ &= 2 \pi \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} e^{-\epsilon r+i \vert k \vert r \cos(\theta) }  r \sin(\theta) \, \text{d}\theta\, \text{d}r \stackrel{z=cos(\theta)}{=} 2 \pi \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-1}^{1} e^{-\epsilon r+i \vert k \vert r z }  r  \, \text{d}z \, \text{d}r \\ &= \frac{2 \pi}{i \vert k \vert} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-\epsilon r+i \vert k \vert r }-e^{-\epsilon r-i \vert k \vert r })   \, \text{d}r = \frac{2 \pi}{i \vert k \vert} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon - i \vert k \vert} -   \frac{1}{\epsilon + i \vert k \vert}\right) \\ &= \frac{4 \pi}{\epsilon^{2}+ \vert k \vert^{2}},\end{aligned}$$
which also holds for $k=0$.
Inserting this into the definition of the Fourier transformation of tempered distributions and using dominated convergence again, we conclude that for all the Schwartz functions $\phi$ we have
$$(\mathcal{F}u_{\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}})(\phi)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R^{3}}}\frac{1}{\vert x \vert} (\mathcal{F}\phi)(x) \, \text{d}x =4 \pi \int\limits_{\mathbb{R^{3}}}\frac{1}{\vert x \vert^{2}} \phi(x) \, \text{d}x = u_{\frac{4 \pi}{ \vert x \vert^{2}}}(\phi) $$
or, loosely speaking, $$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}\right)(k)=\frac{4 \pi}{ \vert k \vert^{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If a physicist encounters an integral in which a physical variable runs to infinity, and if for that very reason the integral is not strictly convergent in a precise mathematical sense, he will usually solve the problem by inserting a so-called **"convergence factor"** in the integrand. This is a function that is nearly equal to 1 in the normal range of (physical) values but drops off sufficiently for very large values to make the integration convergent. This can almost always be justified, on the grounds that in reality physical variables tend to have some upper limit, a cut-off value determined by the physical system.

The most obvious choice in your case is $f(r) = \exp(-\epsilon r)$. That is because performing the integration is then straightforward. At the end of the computation, one will usually take the limit of $\epsilon\to 0$. Note that other choices for the convergence factor are probably equally valid, e.g. a Gaussian, $f(r) = \exp(-(\epsilon r)^2)$.

Comment: I agree with the pertinent comment of M.Wind. The wording of the question by Thobias Hurth was lacking of the context.